# Javadoc not generated for Lombok getter and setter

Tags: javadoc, lombok

I am having a problem with generating Javadoc for Lombok getters and setters. I have tried both suggestions [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html). An example field and its text are as follows:

```
/**  
 *  Identifier of the client
 * 
 *  @param clientID changes the id of the client 
 *  @return id of the client
 */
@Getter @Setter private Integer clientID;
```

However, I see neither the getter nor the setter in the generated Javadoc. I am using 'protected' visibility on Eclipse (Project -> Generate Javadoc...). My Lombok version is 1.12.4. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The javadoc feature does not work in the eclipse javadoc view or hovers. You can generate the javadoc by running [delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html) on the code first and then run the javadoc compiler, as is hinted on the [feature page near the bottom](https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html).

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Comment: Is there any chance to integrate that into the eclipse plugin? It would be very nice to have the javadoc of the fields on the setters and getters.

Comment: The core lombok maintainers did look into it, but the Eclipse AST for javadoc is complex, and IIRC has changed significantly bewteen versions making it hard to maintain.

Comment: Sorry to know this. This issue is keeping our team from using Lombok.

Comment: Will a batch command to `delombok all - generate javadoc - undo delombok all` do the trick?

Comment: I have a suggestion, why not adding an annotation @Doc that will generate the documentation for the field and the methods !!! is it possible ??

Comment: I find Lombok one of the MUST-HAVE libraries in a Java project. The unique thing I miss is a '@Doc' annotation to generate documentation for setters and getters.

Comment: Clarification: The Javadoc is generated, but Eclipse doesn't see it. IntelliJ gets along with the generated Javadoc just fine.